# Prove that the triangle areas are proportional to the radii

Tags: geometry, circles, area

The line $MN$ is the radical axis I created.

Because of its properties, we have $EM=MF, HN=NG, IQ=QL$, and it is perpendicular to $AC$.

Everything is as you see on the diagram below.

Here $(ABC)$ is the area of $\triangle ABC$.

> Prove that $\frac{(EHI)}{(FGL)}=\frac{AE}{CF}$.

Any proofs are appreciated. You could use coordinates or complex numbers if you wish. It could teach me some new approaches.

---

[image]

Comment: Why have you drawn the radical axis?

Comment: @PenasRaul It's because it seems to me it'll be useful here somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using very different labels in my figure.

---

Let circles $\bigcirc A$ and $\bigcirc B$ have radii $a$ and $b$. With elements labeled as in the figure, we can write
$$\frac{|\triangle PTR|}{|\triangle QUS|} = \frac{\frac12 |\overline{PR}|\;|\overline{HK}|}{\frac12 |\overline{QS}|\;|\overline{JL}|} = \frac{a\;|\overline{HK}|}{b\;|\overline{JL}|}\tag{$\star$}$$

[image]

Now, the radical axis (through $M$) bisects *external* tangents $\overline{PQ}$ and $\overline{RS}$, and therefore also segment $\overline{KL}$. Likewise, the axis bisects *internal* tangent $\overline{TU}$, and also $\overline{HJ}$. Thus, $M$ serves as the common midpoint of both $\overline{KL}$ and $\overline{HJ}$, and we have
$$|\overline{HK}| = |\overline{MK}| - |\overline{MH}| = |\overline{ML}|-|\overline{MJ}| = |\overline{JL}|$$
so that $(\star)$ reduces to $a/b$, as desired. $\square$

Comment: Can formal science papers use $AB$ instead of $\overline{AB}$ or $|\overline{AB}|$? My school has never used your notation.

Comment: @mathh: $AB$ is an acceptable substitute ... and may even be preferred. I'm just old-fashioned when it comes to indicating segments with $\overline{\text{overline}}$s and lengths with $|\text{bar}|$s. Writing "$|\triangle ABC|$" for "the area of $\triangle ABC$" is pretty non-standard, but I like it. :)